# DCC error : published field is not a class or interface type

Tags: delphi, class, interface, syntax-error, field

I keep getting this following DCC error, published field 'name' is not a class or interface type for the following class.

```
  TGroup = class
    name:string[32]; <<<========================
    rwFeatures:TFeatures;
    roFeatures:TFeatures;
    levels:TLevels;   
  private

  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Read(var f:file);
    procedure ReadOld(var f:file);
    procedure Write(var f:file);   
  end;
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class is compiled with the [Emit runtime type information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Run-Time_Type_Information_%28Delphi%29) setting enabled. When the class is compiled with runtime type information, the default visibility is `published`. Which means that the short string field is `published`. And short string fields are not allowed to be published.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Classes_and_Objects#Published_Members) says:

> Fields can be published only if they are of a class or interface type.

That's a pretty stringent requirement. It means that you can't publish integer or boolean fields, for example.

I suspect this limitation is because the primary use for published fields is for object references. Think of the components on a form.

Solve the problem using one of these options:

1. Don't emit runtime type information for this class.
2. Make the short string fields public rather than published.
3. Use properties rather than fields.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it was misleading. It will compile with `{$M-}` not because published fields then can have short string types, but because fields without an explicit visibility are then not published.

Comment: @hvd Yes you are quite right. I have misunderstood that until you just explained it. Thank you.

Comment: @hvd I have learnt on this question that I completely misunderstood all the details around `published`. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction. Having read the excellent documentation, I'm not  on the same page as the rest of you!